# How can i use the return statement of a boolean in another method?

Tags: java, class, methods, boolean

I have a method that returns true or false,

```
public boolean confirmVotes()
{
System.out.println("Your vote for President is:" + getVotes() );
System.out.println("your vote for Vice President is:" + getVotes());
System.out.println("Is this correct? Yes or No?");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String answer = keyboard.nextLine();
if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
    return true;
 else 
   return false;
}
```

How do i use this return statement in another method? This is what i am trying to do

```
 public void recordVote()
{
        if  comfirmVotes returns true for X
             do this for y

}
```

Comment: You have already used a return statement of another method inside your first code block (in if condition)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you inspect your confirmVotes method, you will notice that you've already solved this problem:-

```
if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
```

.equalsIgnoreCase(String s) is a method which returns a boolean, and you've already constructed an if statement based on its return value. Thus:-

```
if (confirmVotes())
{
  // Do whatever
}
```

Also worthy of note, you can replace:-

```
if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

with:-

```
return answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes");
```

Comment: This questions was tagged as homework. The idea with these is, to not give the poster the full answer, but instead point him in the right direction.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that you can use the boolean expression without an if statement.

Comment: @nfechner: I'd usually agree with you, however it's hard to point someone in the right direction when the answer is something as minor as `if (confirmVotes())`. Especially since Iain likened it to a function that the OP had already used in the same way. +1

Comment: Yeah, same. I'd find it kind of patronising to be hinting someone towards a question of quite simple syntax. Figured it'd be better to give the answer and then show a couple of similar cases of directly using the return value of a method.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void recordVote() {
    if (confirmVotes()) { // your method should return true. if it does, it will process the if block, if not you can do stuff on the else block

    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void myMethod(){
    if(confirmVotes()){
        doStuff();
    }
    else{
        doOtherStuff();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is how to call a method belong to the same class from a another method of that class. (Because You have already used a return statement of another method inside your first code block.)

You can use **this** keyword for refering to current instance of the class, or if it is call inside a non-static method, you don't need to use that.

e.g:

```
if (this.confirmVotes() == true)
```

or (if the calling method is a member method (non-static) or called method is a static method))

```
if (confirmVotes() == true) {
```

Because **confirmVotes()** method returns true, you can also use **if(confirmVotes())** instead of comparing it to boolean true again.